# How to get variable from path?

Tags: angularjs

I have this path:

```
http://localhost:1234/#/Plya/Home
```

Sometimes the path above can have variable:

```
http://localhost:1234/#/Plya/Home/1234
```

My question is how to get variable `1234` from the path using angularJS?

Comment: You can do that without angular, just good old plain JS.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use in your controller `$routeParams` that contains the variable:

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.userName;
```

In the routing you have to specify:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/configUser/:userName', {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/configUser.html',
            controller: 'configUserController'
        });
});
```

Comment: is :userName optional parameter?

Comment: can contain optional with a question mark (:userName?)

Answer (score 1):

You need `$routeParams`.

When defining your route:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/Plya/Home/:plyaId', {
      templateUrl: 'plya.html',
      controller: 'PlyaController'
    });
```

In PlyaController:

```
module.controller('PlyaController',['$routeParams',function($routeParams) {
  $scope.plyaId = $routeParams.plyaId;
}]);
```